# Repository Branch Policy Edits failing for Build Service unless 'Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines' setting disabled

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, repository

## Background:

- I'm using Terraform to deploy Branch Policies in Azure DevOps from within a (YAML) Pipeline using the [azuredevops provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest).
- Terraform is provided the pipeline's $(System.AccessToken)
- I have the `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines` setting **enabled** in my Project.

## Issue:

When terraform attempts to Apply it hits a permission error.

> Error creating policy in Azure DevOps: TF401027: You need the Git 'EditPolicies' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\{guid}', scope 'Project'.

where {guid} is the Build Service's id (confirmed within the Security Permissions UI).

## I have attempted the following:

- Providing the Build Service (via guid in error above) with 'Edit Policies' Security permission on the Repository
- Ensuring the target Repository is explicitly provided as:

  - `repository` resource defined with pipeline yaml `resources:`

```yaml
resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: {repo id}
      type: git
      name: {repo name}
```

- Pipeline agent job explicitly `uses:` above `repository` resource

```yaml
    - job: Deploy
      uses:
        repositories:
          - {repo id}
```

Is there anything I'm missing in order to provide sufficient 'Edit Policies' permissions to terraform in my pipeline without disabling the `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines` setting?

Comment: if you disable the `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines` is it working?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, if I disable that setting it works. However, I would like to retain this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause of my permissions error.

The policy I was applying in Terraform was using `scope`:

```yaml
    {
      match_type = "DefaultBranch"
    }
```

which produces a Cross-repo branch policy (ie. applying at the All Repository scope)

Switching to `match_type` = 'Exact' resolved the permissions issue.

```yaml
    {
      repository_ref = "refs/heads/main"
      match_type     = "Exact"
    }
```

which makes sense as the pipeline & job is only authorised to modify a few specific repositories, not all current & future.

That leaves one last question:

*How would I provide a pipeline with permission to create/update a Cross-repo branch policy?*

Not sure. I'll keep digging for an answer.

Will update here if I find it.